# How can I connect buttons and select with its options in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, select, binding, vue.js

I got stuck, guys. Maybe there is simple solution to my problem. Please, help me.
Here is the issue.

I have 5 possible options to choose from. Let's say ***[a, b, c, d, e]***

My layout is *two buttons* and *select dropdown menu*.
In other words, I give two possibilities to user:

Either click on one of two buttons or select from list.

So template is kinda

```
<button> A <button>
<button> B <button>
<select v-model="selected">
  <option :value="i" v-for="i in list">i</option>
</select>
```

In my script I have

```
data () {
      return {
         list: ['c', 'd', 'e']
      }
    }
```

How can I combine these three elements into one. Can I somehow use v-model? Cause of now, I can get selected option from list. What should I do then. If I add *@click* event to buttons, what should they handle?

I thought to make computed value, like checking if `selected` is not undefined or equal to `''`, then the option is `selected`. But in order to bind buttons clicked events, I should create methods to handle their state, like

```
data () {
      return {
         list: ['c', 'd', 'e'],
         a: false,
         b: false
      }
    },
methods: {
  handleA () {
    this.a = true
    this.b = false     
  },
  handleB () {
    this.b = true
    this.a = false     
  }
}
```

And then every click will change `false` to `true`, and besides there also needs to be a logic to keep only one `true` state: either for `a` (button A), `b` (button B) or `selected`. It feels too wrong to be true. In my opinion, I'm making things harder. There has to be an easy way.

Comment: So, click button one, value is A, click two, value is B, otherwise pick C,D, or E from the list?

Comment: Yes, and the value can only be one of these 5 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a component. Build the component to support `v-model`.

```
Vue.component("picker",{
  props:["value"],
  data(){
    return {
      list:["c","d","e"],
      currentValue: this.value,
      selectedValue: ""
    }
  },
  template:`
    <div>
      <button @click="currentValue = 'a'">A</button>
      <button @click="currentValue = 'b'">B</button>
      <select @change="currentValue = $event.target.value" v-model="selectedValue">
          <option value="">Select a value</option>
          <option v-for="item in list" :value="item" :key="item">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  watch:{
    currentValue(newValue){
      if (!this.list.includes(newValue))
        this.selectedValue = "" 

      this.$emit('input', newValue)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    pickedValue: null
  }
})
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/rmRgdJ?editors=1010).

Comment: So, I can ignore `v-model` and simply assign the values `@click="currentValue = ' _somevalue_'` or `$event.target.value` 
accroding to each event happened, clicks or option selection.

It worked for me, but I really want to get rest of code. 

`currentValue: this.value` 

`watch: {
currentValue(newValue){
this.$emit('input', newValue)}`

We are watching every change of `currentValue`. When it is changed, we emit event named *input* passing to its listener `newValue`. When do we listen to this event? Why do we need to use this word here `currentValue = this.value`

Comment: @KarénMarkosyan All the code you are asking about is so that you can use `v-model` *outside* of the component. The way `v-model` works is it passed a `value` property to your component and it listens for `input` events. `currentValue: this.value` is there so that when the component is initialized, if the expression passed in `v-model` already has a value, then the component will be initialized with the value.

Comment: @KarénMarkosyan Basically [this documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) covers all of that.

Comment: Thanks for answer and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that if you `v-model` in a select and the variable bound to the `v-model` gets a value that is not in your options, the variable gets reset to null.

You have to come up with some special-case handling to get around that. One way is to set the select list to `v-model` a settable computed that interprets non-listed values as null and writes non-null values to the `selected` data item.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: null,
    list: ['c', 'd', 'e']
  },
  computed: {
    proxySelected: {
      get() {
        return this.list.includes(this.selected) ? this.selected : null;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          this.selected = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="selected = 'a'"> A </button>
  <button @click="selected = 'b'"> B </button>
  <select v-model="proxySelected">
    <option :value="i" v-for="i in list">{{i}}</option>
  </select>
  Selected value: {{selected}}
</div>
```

Comment: I got it. In the end, I pass value from button to droplist and then `v-model` handles its value. However, it is not desired to see my `a` and `b` options inside of dropdown list. Interestingly, when you click any button, its value is being added to list, *and that newly added option appears on top*. Anyway It's a working solution, thanks for answer.